# Draw a line with raspberry pi 3

Tags: user-interface, assembly, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to draw a line using this example I found online, but when I run it, it just prints the resolution of the screen I am using. I already connected different monitors but it still does the same. Some help on what I might be doing wrong?

This is draw.s

```
#---------------------------------
# For screen size 
# 1824x984
#---------------------------------
 .text
 .align 2
 .global main
main:
    #-------------------------
    #get screen address
    #-------------------------
    bl getScreenAddr
    ldr r1,=pixelAddr
    str r0,[r1]
    #-------------------------
    #draw line usign pixels
    #-------------------------
    mov r5,#0       @x count
loop:
    cmp r5, #1824
    bgt end

    ldr r0,=pixelAddr
    ldr r0,[r0] 

    ldr r1,=x
    ldr r1,[r1]

    ldr r2,=y
    ldr r2,[r2]

    ldr r3,=green
    ldr r3,[r3]

    bl pixel

    ldr r1,=x
    ldr r7,[r1]
    add r7,#1
    str r7,[r1]

    add r5,#1

    b loop
end:
    #-------------------------
    #draw a single pixel
    #-------------------------
    ldr r0,=pixelAddr
    ldr r0,[r0]
    mov r1,#900
    mov r2,#100  
    mov r3,#24
    bl pixel
    #exit syscall
    mov r7,#1
    swi 0
.data
.balign 4
.global pixelAddr
pixelAddr: .word 0
x:        .word 0       @value in x
y:        .word 900     @value in y
red:      .word 192
blue:     .word 24
green:    .word 7
.end
```

And this is the pixel.c library

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<linux/fb.h>
#include<sys/mman.h>

int fbfd = 0;
struct fb_var_screeninfo vinfo;
struct fb_fix_screeninfo finfo;
long int screensize = 0;
int   xRes = 0;
int   yRes = 0; 
char  *fbp = 0;

//-----------------------------------------------
// Get screen buffer memory address
//-----------------------------------------------
int getScreenAddr(){

  int addr;

  // Open the file for reading and writing
  fbfd = open("/dev/fb0", O_RDWR);
  if (!fbfd) {
    printf("Error: cannot open framebuffer device.\n");
    return(1);
  }

  // Get fixed screen information
  if (ioctl(fbfd, FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO, &finfo)) {
    printf("Error reading fixed information.\n");
  }

  // Get variable screen information
  if (ioctl(fbfd, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, &vinfo)) {
    printf("Error reading variable information.\n");
  }
  printf("%dx%d,%d bits per pixel\n", vinfo.xres, vinfo.yres, vinfo.bits_per_pixel );

  xRes = vinfo.xres;
  yRes = vinfo.yres;

  // map framebuffer to user memory 
  screensize = finfo.smem_len;

  fbp = (char*)mmap(0, screensize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fbfd, 0);
  addr = (int)fbp;
  close(fbfd);
  return(addr);
}

//-----------------------------------------------
// Draw pixel in x,y coordinates with color c
//-----------------------------------------------
void pixel(int memPtr, int x, int y, int c){
  memset((char*)memPtr + 2*(xRes*y +x), c, 2);
}
```

Comment: Do you run this from within a graphical environment? Because this code looks like it needs to be run with no X server running.